# Shopify - Display how many orders a customer placed on the packing slip

Tags: shopify, liquid, orders

I am trying to display how many orders a customer has placed on their order packing slip in shopify.

This code seems perfect but it is not working:

```
{% if customer %}
{% if customer.orders_count == 1 %}
first order
{% else %}
More than 1 orders
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I also tried to just display the number by using {{customer.orders_count}}
and nothing shows up.

Is it not possible to display this type of data on a packing slip? Is the packing slip limited only to the current order?

I am fairly new to this and solving this would be very helpful to me.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure customer is something you can see in a packing slip?  https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/adding-customer-total-number-of-orders-to-packing-slip/td-p/1478413

Comment: Thanks Jerry looks like you are correct. It doesn't look like that data is available on a packing slip.